# Get the term set name that is being used in sharepoint sites

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I have been tasked to get the MMS term sets that are being used based on terms(not with null value of MMS column in the list's items ) in all the sites so that only those MMS terms sets can get migrated to the other sharepoint environment.  On a base level I'm using below script

```
    $FieldCollection= (Get-SPWeb https:/sharepoint.com/sites/pssl/mgmt).Lists.Fields 
$MetadataField = New-Object psobject
$MetadataField | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "ParentListUrl" -value ""
$MetadataField | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "ParentListTitle" -value ""
$MetadataField | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "FieldTitle" -value ""
$MetadataField | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "FieldId" -value ""

$matches = @();
foreach($field in $FieldCollection)
{
    if($field.GetType().Name -ne "TaxonomyField"){
        continue;
    }
    #if($field.TermSetId.ToString() -ne $TermSet.Id.ToString()){continue;}
    $tf = $MetadataField | Select-Object *;
    $tf.ParentListUrl = $field.ParentList.ParentWeb.Url;
    $tf.ParentListTitle = $field.ParentList.Title;
    $tf.FieldTitle = $field.Title;
    $tf.FieldId = $field.ID;

    $matches += $tf;
}
return $matches;
```

but it returns only managed metadata columns defined in the list, but not they are being used in the list. Can anybody help me to achieve the task.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert in Sharepoint API, but I'm trying to understand what the problem is to help you and I can't.

I notice that you create an object `$MetadataField` before a loop, then kind of create a replica `$MetadataField | Select-Object *` and then add in a array.

As you say, the returned objects should only have the columns of `ParentListUrl`,`ParentListTitle`,`FieldTitle` and `FieldId` which is what I expect from the sample above. Can you elaborate more on what you are looking for? Maybe update the entire function into your question and post your returned expectation. this way I can try to help you out.

Btw, the `;` is not required and you should create a new instance of the object within the loop. You can use the same method or first create a hash key that drives the properties of a custom object. For example in your loop adjust the following.

```
$hash=@{
   Property1="Value1"
   Property2="Value2"
}

New-Object -Type PSObject -Property $hash
```

Also if you function returns directly each found item without extra processing, then you can skip adding them in an array and just write in the output like I do in my example. To make it more clear, if I would put a loop around my example in a function and execute, then I would get a recordset with custom object with Property1 and Property2